# Function addrow is not defined after add jquery noconflict

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery script that need to be implemented with JQuery noconflict but it seem to break the functions inside document ready

#### jQuery:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    var rowNum = 0;

    function addRow(frm) {
        rowNum++;
        var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '"><input type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value=""> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"></p>';
        $j('#itemRows').append(row);
    }

    function removeRow(rnum) {
        $j('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
    }
});
```

#### HTML:

```
<input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add Row" />
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tu3yqf8y/

the question is how to get working the functions inside jquery no conflict document ready?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tu3yqf8y/12/

Comment: the error i got is `TypeError: $j is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions called from `onXYZ` attribute handlers must be globals. Your functions are not globals, because they're nested inside the `ready` callback.

Rather than using `onXYZ` attributes, hook up the handlers via jQuery. In this case, I'd probably go for a delegated handler:

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    var rowNum = 0;

    // Direct handler for adding (since you only have
    // one button and it's already there)
    $j(".add").on("click", function() {
        var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '"><input type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value=""> <input type="button" value="-" class="delete"></p>';
        $j('#itemRows').append(row);
    });

    // Delegated handler for removing (as you add these
    // dynamically)
    $j("#itemRows").on("click", ".delete", function() {
      $j(this).closest('p').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itemRows"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" class="add">
```

You *can* still have row IDs if you like, but you don't need them, so I didn't use them above.

Comment: By using `$j(document).ready(function ($) {` at the beginning, you can still use just `$` inside the closure (which may be named, btw) parameter of the `ready` function.

Comment: @laruiss: Indeed, there are about 20 ways to write the above.